# Move all array elements one space up in python NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to do a sorting algorithm and I need to do something like this:

```
arr = numpy.array([2,4,5,6])
#some function here or something
array([5,2,4,6])
#element "5" moved from position 3 to 1, and all of the others moved up one position
```

What I mean is I want to change an element's position (index) and move all the other elements up one position. Is this possible?

Comment: So do you know the position of the element to be taken to the first position?

Comment: It doesnt have to be the first position, but yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.roll()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) with a subset assignment:

```
arr = numpy.array([2,4,5,6])

arr[:3] = numpy.roll(arr[:3],1)

print(arr)
[5 2 4 6]
```

Comment: this is also useful, thanks.

Comment: does the `numpy.roll` create a copy of the array or it does it in-place in the same array?

Comment: It creates a new one, hence the need to assign the result to a subset of the original

Answer (score 0):

If you know the position/index of the element to be shifted, then you could do:

```
indx = 2
np.r_[arr[indx], np.delete(arr, indx)]
Out[]: array([5, 2, 4, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in-place without the need of creating first an intermediate array of *n-1* elements and then creating another final array by concatenation. Instead, you could try this:

```
idx = 2
tmp = arr[idx]
arr[1:idx+1] = arr[0:idx]
arr[0] = tmp
```

So there are more than one ways of doing this, and the choice depends upon your algorithm's constraints.

Comment: thankss! thats what i was looking for.